# StackNavigator's child component rendered twice when called outside of its parent

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) for navigating between the screens in my React Native application. My screens structure is:

```
 - DrawerNavigator    
    - HomeScreen    
    - MoviesStackNavigator    
      - MoviesListScreen    
      - MovieDetailsScreen    
    - DiscoverScreen
```

Now I want to navigate and pass some params from DiscoverScreen to MoviesListScreen.

Here is my code:

DiscoverScreen.js

```
onSearchConfirm() {
    this.setState({searching: true})


    var params = {
        sort_by: this.state.sortBy,
        year: this.state.releaseYear,
        with_genres: this.state.genreIds.join(',')
    };

    const _this = this;

    return fetch(Configuration.TMDB_BASE_URL
                .concat('/discover/movie?')
                .concat(Utility.stringFromQueryParams({...params, api_key: Configuration.TMDB_API_KEY})))
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonResponse => {
            _this.setState({searching: false});

            const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'MoviesList',
                params: {data: jsonResponse}
            })

            _this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)

        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()))
}
```

DrawerNavigator:

```
export default MenuNavScreen = DrawerNavigator(
{
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Movies: {
        screen: MoviesStackNavigator
    },
    DiscoverMovies: {
        screen: DiscoverScreen
    },
    About: {
        screen: AboutScreen
    },
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
})
```

MoviesStackNavigator:

```
export default MoviesStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    MoviesList: {
        screen: MoviesListScreen
    },
    MovieDetails: {
        screen: MovieDetailsScreen
    },
});
```

And finally, the code where I am checking for the params 
MoviesListScreen:

```
//...
componentWillMount() { //THIS IS CALLED TWICE

    if(!this.props.navigation.state.params) {
        MoviesService.getPopularMovies()
            .then(movies => {
                this.setState({movies: movies.results})
            })
            .catch(err => Alert.alert(err.toString()))
    }
    else {
        this.setState({movies: this.props.navigation.state.params.data.results})
    }
}
//...
```

Well, the last piece of code is executed twice. First with the "data" param undefined, and second time with the properly populated param. Where is my mistake? Thank you all :)

EDIT: To be clear, this is the result of the problem described above:

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjRDu.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some time, I realized that i can solve the problem by replacing DiscoverScreen with a new DiscoverStackNavigator and then set DiscoverScreen, MoviesListScreen and MovieDetailsScreen as its child screens. So my code is look like this now:

DrawerNavigator:

```
export default MenuNavScreen = DrawerNavigator(
{
    Home: {
        screen: HomeScreen
    },
    Movies: {
        screen: MoviesStackNavigator
    },
    DiscoverMovies: {
        screen: DiscoverStackNavigator
    },
    About: {
        screen: AboutScreen
    },
},
{
    initialRouteName: 'Home'
})
```

DiscoverStackNavigator:

```
export default DiscoverStackNavigator = StackNavigator({
    DiscoverMovies: {
        screen: DiscoverScreen
    }
    DiscoverMoviesList: {
        screen: MoviesListScreen
    },
    DiscoverMovieDetails: {
        screen: MovieDetailsScreen
    },
});
```

Navigating to MoviesScreen:

```
onSearchConfirm() {
    //...code before

    return fetch(Configuration.TMDB_BASE_URL
                .concat('/discover/movie?')
                .concat(Utility.stringFromQueryParams({...params, api_key: Configuration.TMDB_API_KEY})))
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(jsonResponse => {
            _this.setState({searching: false});

            const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
                routeName: 'DiscoverMoviesList', // we changed the route name
                params: {data: jsonResponse}
            })

            _this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)

        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err.toString()))
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct approach, but it works great.